# How can I set a default value if a user doesn't send an input in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Right now - I have a input field on my html that Thymeleaf sticks a '0' in when the page loads. If for some reason that '0' is erased and the form is submitted - I get a NumberFormatException.

Is there a way I can automatically make it '0' if the form is submitted without anything in the input form?

Here's my html form (my th:object is ${npf})

```
<div class="col-md-2 form-outline">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="addConcealed" th:field="${npf.numConcealed}" placeholder="C" />
     <label class="form-label text-muted" for="addConcealed">Concealed</label>
</div>
```

Here's the error I get:

```
[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for property 'numConcealed'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""]
```

Anyway I can have it default to 0 if there's nothing in the input field rather than erroring out and making the user enter a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to handle this:

1. Turn your variable `numConcealed` into an `Long` instead of a `long`.  Deal with a null value when they erase the field.
2. Use JavaScript, capture the submit just change the field value back to 0 if they submit a blank text field.
3. Create your own `String` to `int` [Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#core-convert) and register it for that field.  Should work the same way as the normal converter (whatever that is) except it would return 0 for nulls.